# Control zoom in SAS Enterprise?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I'm using SAS Enterprise Guide 5.1.

My window looks like this:

[image]

The text is huge - I'd like to zoom out so I can see more of the code in my program (obviously this one is just a placeholder).

How can I control the level of zoom?

I tried using `ctrl` and the mouse-wheel. No luck. I've trawled through toolbar options and found nothing. The solution [here](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/Font-size-is-huge-in-enhanced-editor/m-p/290292#M19822) requires changing Windows Settings - unfortunately that is not an option for me.

Comment: You can just change the font size - would that be an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's a dynamic zoom option. What I do is customize the font to make it smaller (and more aesthetically pleasing):

- Tools
- Options
- SAS Programs
- Editor Options
- Appearance

gets you there, then select Lucida Console 9pt as your font, or whatever you find best for you.

Answer (score 2):

Control-mouse wheel works [as of Enterprise Guide 7.12](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2016/02/28/zoom-view-sas-enterprise-guide/), so ask your IT department for an upgrade!

Comment: Cheers for the answer. I'll ask, but I think I know the response already... ;)